# A* (star) algorithm: understanding the f/g/h scores

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, a-star

I am trying to implement A* algorithm in Java, but I am not sure if I understand the f/g/h scores correctly.  I am helping myself with the [pseudocode of A* on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Pseudocode). Here is a bit of the pseudocode:

```
while openSet is not empty
    current := the node in openSet having the lowest fScore[] value
    if current = goal
        return reconstruct_path(cameFrom, current)

    openSet.Remove(current)
    closedSet.Add(current)
    for each neighbor of current
        if neighbor in closedSet
            continue        // Ignore the neighbor which is already evaluated.
        // The distance from start to a neighbor
        tentative_gScore := gScore[current] + dist_between(current, neighbor)
        if neighbor not in openSet  // Discover a new node
            openSet.Add(neighbor)
        else if tentative_gScore >= gScore[neighbor]
            continue        // This is not a better path.

        // This path is the best until now. Record it!
        cameFrom[neighbor] := current
        gScore[neighbor] := tentative_gScore
        fScore[neighbor] := gScore[neighbor] + heuristic_cost_estimate(neighbor, goal)

return failure
```

What I don't understand is this part:

```
else if tentative_gScore >= gScore[neighbor]
        continue        // This is not a better path.
```

How come the neighbour already has a G Score? I am interpreting the algorithm in this way:

1. Pick a node from the open set with the lowest F score. (F Score = G Score + H Score, where G Score is the cost of the current path from start to the current node (the one we are going to pick from the open set) and the H score is the cost from the current node (the one we are going to pick) to the end node, let's say we picked Manhattan distance for the heuristic.)
2. Then, check all neighbours of the node we just picked (current node).
3. If it is already in the closed set, skip it. If it is not, check if it is in the open set. If not, calculated F score for this neighbour where G score is now G score of the current node + G score from current to the neighbour. This is what is called tentative_gScore in the code I provided. H score changes to value calculated from the neighbour to the end node.

And here is the question:

What is the gScore[neighbour]? Where was it calculated? What is the value of it? Tentative_gScore I understand, but where do we get the gScore of a neighbour so that we can test the condition:

```
 else if tentative_gScore >= gScore[neighbor]
        continue        // This is not a better path.
```

Comment: This is not a Java question. And it is too broad methinks.

Comment: Sorry, honest mistake. I am coding in Java and I simply put Java in the tags. >.< Anyways, I have figured it out now. :)

Comment: If you got a good answer ... you could consider answering your question yourself. Or to delete it. It doesn't too make sense to have that question sit around here like it is right now.

Comment: I'd delete the question as @GhostCat suggested. There are already 716 questions tagged with `a-star` on stackoverflow, and the algorithm really isn't that complicated that we need so many questions about it.

Comment: Good choice. More mature than what comes from most newbies (or even more experienced users)!

Comment: As far as I am concerned, the question can be deleted. :)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I got it.

If the neighbour is found for the first time, you do not even compare the g scores, you just simply add it into the open set.

If the neighbour is already in the open set (this also means that it has some sort of a g score):
The gScore[neighbour] is the g score of the previously found neighbour that was added into the open set. If you find this neighbour again, you can compare the g scores (the new g score with the old g score (found previously)). If the new score is better (i.e. lower) change the scores and parent node accordingly.

Simple as that. :)